# In Radio button custom version, the form returns the id when it is submitted. How to get the Value in the form instead of id?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

Below is my code for radio button in the form

```
<div data---="radiobutton__form.sex__datasource:list;required:true;label:Gender">
    <script type="text/html">
        <div class="ui-radiobutton-custom">
            <div>{{ name }}</div>
        </div>
    </script>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var list = [{ name: 'Male', id: 1 }, { name: 'Female', id: 2 }, { name: 'Other', id: 3 }]
</script>
```

Comment: This question had nothing to do with `JRadioButton` (in the title) and `JComponent` (in the tags). Those are components from the Swing based GUI Toolkit of Java. Java is quite distinct from Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy, just set `value:name_of_property_to_output`, example:

```
<div data---="radiobutton__YOUR_PATH__datasource:YOUR_DATASOURCE;value:YOUR_OUTPUT_PROPERTY">Choose somehthing</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. Works now. Whats the similar thing for Date that I should use? I am getting 'null' value in my db. The value from datepicker is not reflected. I am using this -  <div data---="input__form.date__type:date;required:true;">Date of Birth</div>

Comment: First: check `form` object if it contains required data and then check your server-side if received required data. j-Input supports only two formats of date: yyyy-MM-dd or dd.MM.yyyy + it uses j-DatePicker component.